# unable to remove react element onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove an element when i click on the x button. Below is my code

```
 const onRemoveItem = (el) => {
    var element = el;
    if (element != null) {
      element.remove();
    }
    //   chartInstance.resize();
  };

  const removeStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    left: "11px",
    top: 0,
    cursor: "pointer"
  };

  return (
    <ResponsiveGridLayout layouts={layout}>
      <div key="1">
        <NewvsReturnVisitors />
        <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} onClick={onRemoveItem}>
          x
        </span>
      </div>
      <div key="2">
        <NewvsReturnVisitors />
        <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} onClick={onRemoveItem}>
          x
        </span>
      </div>
     <div key="3">
        <NewvsReturnVisitors />
        <span className="remove" style={removeStyle} onClick={onRemoveItem}>
          x
        </span>
      </div>
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
  );
```

but it keep returning me remove is not a function, is there a way in react to remove an element like how it will work in html?

This is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-with-resizable-forked-dlywd?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Removing elements in React is done by changing the state of your component, and when your component is re-rendered it depends upon the state which elements are rendered into the output.

Comment: Is there just going to be one `span` that you can remove or many?

Comment: there will be mutiple div that i will want to delete, each div will have one span

Comment: i have updated my question to reflect, that i will have many div that will have the x button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain an array of displayed items. If the id of a div is *in* the array just add a class to hide it.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ hidden, setHidden ] = useState([]);

  // When you click on the X get the
  // id of the closest div, and add it to state
  function handleClick(e) {
    const div = e.target.closest('div');
    const { id } = div.dataset;
    const newState = [...hidden, Number(id)];
    setHidden(newState);
  }

  // Small function that each div calls
  // to determine if the hidden class
  // should be applied
  function isHidden(id) {
    return hidden.includes(id) && 'hidden';
  }
  
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      <div className={isHidden(1)} data-id="1">
        One&nbsp;
        <span class="remove">x</span>
      </div>
      <div className={isHidden(2)} data-id="2">
        Two&nbsp;
        <span class="remove">x</span>
      </div>
      <div className={isHidden(3)} data-id="3">
        Three&nbsp;
        <span class="remove">x</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
span { cursor: pointer; color: red; }
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```